# Azure AD login in UWP app doesn't work for some windows devices

Tags: c#, windows, azure, uwp, azure-active-directory

In My UWP app I have integrate Azure AD login. Once the AD popup comes for some devices the login process works fine. But for some devices I get can't connect to the service error when clicking login button.

[image]

What did I miss here. Both the devices are connected to the same network. I have android and ios apps which integrated AD login and those devices didn't get this issue.

```
 private static OidcClientOptions GetOidcOptions(bool isEnableWindowsAuthentication=false)
    {
        string logInfo = "OidcClient Options: RedirectUri: " + WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri;
        Utility.WriteErrorsToLogViaMessenger("IdentityManager-GetOidcOptions", new Exception(logInfo));

        string address = Utility.ReplaceLastOccurrence(Global.ServerUrlAuth, "/" + Global.Identifier, string.Empty).TrimEnd('/');
      
        return new OidcClientOptions
        {
            Authority = address,
            ClientId = "companykey.openid.windows",
            Scope = VersionAdaptiveCode.DocVersioning? ApplicationConstants.ScopeForIdentityManager + ApplicationConstants.DocumentDownloadIdentifier : ApplicationConstants.ScopeForIdentityManager,
            RedirectUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri,
            Browser = new WabBrowser(enableWindowsAuthentication: isEnableWindowsAuthentication),
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri,
        };
    }
```

This is the code for the wabBrowser.

```
 private async Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsyncCore(BrowserOptions options, bool silentMode)
    {
        var wabOptions = WebAuthenticationOptions.None;

        if (_enableWindowsAuthentication)
        {
            wabOptions |= WebAuthenticationOptions.UseCorporateNetwork;
        }
        if (silentMode)
        {
            wabOptions |= WebAuthenticationOptions.SilentMode;
        }

        WebAuthenticationResult wabResult;

        try
        {
            if (string.Equals(options.EndUrl, WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                wabResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                    wabOptions, new Uri(options.StartUrl));
            }
            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.EndUrl))
                {
                    wabResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                    wabOptions, new Uri(options.StartUrl), WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri());
                }
                else
                {
                    wabResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                    wabOptions, new Uri(options.StartUrl), new Uri(options.EndUrl));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.WriteErrorsToLogViaMessenger("WabBrowser-InvokeAsyncCore", ex);

            return new BrowserResult
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.UnknownError,
                Error = ex.ToString()
            };
        }

        if (wabResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
        {
            return new BrowserResult
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success,
                Response = wabResult.ResponseData
            };
        }
        else if (wabResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
        {
            return new BrowserResult
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.HttpError,
                Error = string.Concat(wabResult.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString())
            };
        }
        else if (wabResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.UserCancel)
        {
            return new BrowserResult
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.UserCancel
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new BrowserResult
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.UnknownError,
                Error = "Invalid response from WebAuthenticationBroker"
            };
        }
    }
```

I have logged the errors and the devices which fails login returns **401** for the following request

```
wabResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                    wabOptions, new Uri(options.StartUrl));
```